# TypeError: mongodb.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

i tried to fix this errors in my project based on express js i found that i can't find the error

here's my code

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

mongodb.connect(
  process.env.CONNECTION,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      module.exports = client;
      const app = require("./app");
      app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
        console.log("connected");
      });
    }
  }
);
```

and the error i'm getting is this one

> Users/ismailtaibi/Documents/GitHub/worketplace-web/db.js:4
> mongodb.connect(
> ^
>
> TypeError: mongodb.connect is not a function
> at Object. (/Users/ismailtaibi/Documents/GitHub/worketplace-web/db.js:4:9)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Answer (score 0):

You can try below connect way.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
try {
    await client.connect();
    await listDatabases(client);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

or

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mymondb", function (err, db) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('mongodb is running!');
  db.close();
});
```

or using `mongoose`

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db1', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false }))


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Comment: it is not working sir

Comment: i got the same error

Comment: try to use `mongoose`